# How to improve the performance of stored procedure calls through Entity Framework in a C# API?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, query-optimization

I have an API written in C# using Entity Framework in combination with SQL Server. On the SQL Server side, I have several procedures that I invoke through Entity Framework from a controller.

Here is an example of one procedure call:

```
var result = context.MyProcedure.FromSqlRaw(
"EXECUTE [MyDB].[dbo].[MyProcedure] @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4",
    new SqlParameter("@Param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("@Param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("@Param3", param3),
    new SqlParameter("@Param4", param4 == "all" ? DBNull.Value : param4)
).ToList();

return Ok(new { result });
```

Previously, calls to stored procedures were executed in ~2 seconds, but now they take ~20 seconds. At the same time, operations such as data filtering, retrieval by ID, and authorization are performed quickly.

After conducting a test without using Entity Framework in a new console application, I found that the procedure executes within the expected 2-3 seconds. However, replacing the call through Entity Framework with similar code in ASP.NET MVC leads to the same delay of ~20 seconds. It seems that the delay is associated with the process of fetching data after the procedure call.

How can the performance of such calls be improved? Are there ways to optimize or alternative methods of invoking stored procedures through Entity Framework to reduce execution time?

As described above, I tried running the procedure from the same database through an empty console application without Entity Framework, and it worked very quickly.

Comment: The parameters have a look of a catch all query; do you have distinct queries for the difference permutations, or are you using dynamic SQL or forcing a recompile? We can't offer insight into how to improve a batch's performance when you don't give us that batch.

Comment: The place to increase performance is the SP and you need to provide that.

Comment: I find this surprising - there isn't *much* that EF can do wrong here; have you checked for transactions and in particular: blocking? If all else fails... have you tried using Dapper instead? EF feels like overkill for this, when it could just be `connection.Execute("MyProcedure", new { param1, param2, param3, ... });`

Comment: Please show the procedure definition, and share the query plans for the fast and slow versions via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. You can get these from the plan cache, or using a XEvent trace. Please also show the full table definitions with indexes for all relevant tables. We can't answer this otherwise, as it's almost certainly a parameter sniffing issue.

Comment: It is all done with the driver in the connection string.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/#google_vignette

Comment: @jdweng ah yes, the important `,Speed=Fast` connection-string setting :) (more seriously: can you be more specific? *usually* this is not hugely relevant, and is more of an absolute "can I connect yes/no?" or *perhaps* scalability via pooling etc, but not raw speed)

Comment: @Charlieface : Did you look at the link?  The speed will vary a lot if you use an Oledb driver instead of a ODBC driver or Net.

Comment: @MarcGravell : You are wrong.  For example ODBC was the older interface but there were compatibility issues.  So the newer interface Oledb was developed which solved the interface compatibility, but was much slower.  ODBC was suppose to be obsoleted, but many stayed with ODBC because it was much faster.

Comment: @jdweng Almost nobody uses `OleDbConnection` etc when connecting to SQL Server, as there is the specific `SqlConnection` for it. If OP is using that they would have to say, but the issue is very likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: @jdweng in most cases, the provider/driver isn't specified and will cause an error if supplied - with that being specified instead directly via the ADO.NET provider *used explicitly in code*, i.e. `new SqlConnection(...)` etc